# How To Access Multidimensional Array Elements to Multiply Them

Tags: php, arrays, html, multidimensional-array

Create a multidimensional array that contains the measurements, in inches, for several boxes that a shipping company might use to determine the volume of a box.I am having trouble accessing the elements that I actually want. I just need to multiple the 3 integers from length width and depth.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>DTD and Box Array</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
$boxArray = array   (
                    'Small Box' => array(12, 10, 2.5),
                    'Medium Box' => array(30, 20, 4),
                    'Large Box' => array(60, 40, 11.5)
                    );


echo '<table border="1">';
echo '<tr><th>Length</th><th>Width</th><th>Depth</th></tr>';
foreach ($boxArray as $k => $v)
    {
    echo $k.': '.$v[0].' x '.$v[1].' x '.$v[2].' = ' .$v[0]*$v[1]*$v[2].'<br>'; 
    }

    foreach( $boxArray as $boxArray )
{
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach( $boxArray as $key )
    {
        echo '<td>'.$key.'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}

// Length * width * depth - dont know how get the integers.
// This echo isnt grabbing the integers i want

// Multiply small box length * width * height


?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You seem to be overwriting the `$boxArray` vaiable in your `foreach` loop

2) `echo $boxArray[1][0] , $boxArray[1][0] ,$boxArray[3,0];` isn't correct, you need `echo $boxArray[1][0] .','. $boxArray[1][0] .','. $boxArray[3,0];`

3) `$boxArray[1][0]` references a string "Medium Box"

4) `$boxArray[3,0]` isn't a correct key reference and would return null

Should the "Small Box", "Medium Box", "Large Box" be array keys?

ie

`$boxArray = array (
                  "Small Box" => array(12,10,2.5),
                  etc...
                  )`

I've got a feeling that what you meant to do is this:

```
$boxArray = array   (
                    'Small Box' => array(12, 10, 2.5),
                    'Medium Box' => array(30, 20, 4),
                    'Large Box' => array(60, 40, 11.5)
                    );

foreach ($boxArray as $k => $v)
    {
    echo $k.': '.$v[0].' x '.$v[1].' x '.$v[2].' = ' .$v[0]*$v[1]*$v[2].'<br>'; 
    }
```

If your array is in the correct format:

```
    foreach ($boxArray as $v)
    {
    echo $v[0].": ".$v[1].' x '.$v[2].' x '.$v[3].' = ' $v[1]*$v[2]*$v[3]; 
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate it, I think there is an error in the foreach syntax well that just what php is saying.Also the main goal is just being able to get the integers in the table and multiple them for each box size.

Comment: I edited my code, also thank you, im using 2 foreach loops idk if thats correct but its working.